# Custom Shipping Rate

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I'm trying to customize my onepage checkout in magento. The process is to place orders to the company. Apparently I have set a custom table rate in magento where in I have 2 choices. First choice is Victoria (Australia), where in depending on item size there is a fixed rate for that, while the rest of Australia has the same rate.

Apparently when I use my onepage checkout, I encounter 2 errors:

1st error is that when I am in guest mode, when I fill up the billing information, after I go to the shipping method, it says that my shipping method is unavailable, even if I had already inputted the correct address.

My second error is that when I am using a customer account, everything works fine for the 1st time, then if I try to place another order, it shows the error.

I'm thinking of two ways right now to solve it:

Since I need to fix the problem right away, could I remove the shipping method altogether and just create my own computation at the review tab and save the shipping fee in the end?

Or I try to fix the problem on how the shipping method works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found matrix-rate free plugin for magento online. A great alternative instead of manipulating it in the backend. I tried it and it immediately worked, though you need to check if you have the data you need in your database. Use the same steps as you were in modifying table rates, as there will be a new tab for the matrix-rate plugin in the configuration->shipping methods tab.